# How to check if the class member pointer is class or struct type in c++11?

Tags: c++

How can I check if the class member pointer is of class or struct type in c++11?

There are 2 methods that check which class a member's pointer is :

```
is_member_pointer<type>::value
is_member_object_pointer<type>::value
```

However, these 2 methods cannot check whether the member pointer is from basic(int,char,float...etc) type or class type.

```
class Test
{
 public:
   int a;
};

class TestClass
{
 public:
    Test aa;
};

int main()
{
  //i want to trait if it is class type or not from member var pointer
  //like this....
  cout<<is_class_member_pointer<Test TestClass::*>::value<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

How can I properly do this?

[p.s]

1. is_class
   : It must be a pure class type. It can not use at class member pointer.
   So it can use like is_class::value;
   but, it can not use at class member pointer type like Test TestClass::*
   So i can not use this.
2. is_fundamental
   : It must be a basic type like float, int.
   It can not use at class member pointer like int TestClass::*.

Comment: You can combine traits. Like e.g. `some_trait::value && some_other_trait::value`

Comment: Are you looking for [`std::is_fundamental`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_fundamental)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for answering, May i ask some detail answer about some_trait?

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for answering, But std::is_fundamental seems  only can use in pure basic type. int, float ,double...etc. Not in member pointer  like int Class:* .

Comment: Oh that's just some pseudo example stuff, not any real trait. See e.g. [this type support reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types) for actual standard traits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really have the type `Test TestClass::*` or `int TestClass::*`, you can just leave off the later part and do `std::is_fundamental<Test>::value` or `std::is_class<Test>::value`.  But that doesn't work so well if you actually want to find this out when the pointer-to-member type is a type template parameter or other typedef.

For that, you can use partial specialization to pick apart the compound type:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct is_class_member_pointer : std::false_type {};

template <typename MemType, class ClassType>
struct is_class_member_pointer<MemType ClassType::*>
    : std::is_class<MemType> {};
```

Other custom traits like `is_fundamental_member_pointer` could be similarly defined.  (Keep in mind that fundamental, class, and function aren't the only possibilities.  A member could also be a pointer, reference, array, enum, ...)